# Align header elements vertically gatsby JS, SCSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, gatsby

I have a nav bar that I've made in Gatsby using SCSS to style it. For some reason, the "Luke" element and the rest of the list are slightly misaligned vertically. I'm not sure why and have tried vertical align which didn't work. I'm using Gatsby, SCSS.

header.js

```
return(
        <header className={headerStyles.header}>
            <h1 className={headerStyles.logo}>Luke</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul className={headerStyles.navList}>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="blog">Blog</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="contact">Contact</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
```

header.module.scss

```
.header{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-list{
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-item{
    color: white;
    font-size: .9rem;
    margin-right: 1.3rem;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the post-processed source, we can see the final HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you have provided, it already looks vertically aligned. Is there any other css affecting the page?

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-list {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  color: white;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-right: 1.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class='header'>
  <h1 class='logo'>Luke</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class='navList'>
      <li>
        <a class='navItem'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class='navItem'>About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class='navItem'>Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class='navItem'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```